# ¿Saben cual podria ser el problema y como solucionar que mi dominio no consuma tantos recursos del CPU del servidor?

Tags: servidor, cpanel

Ya les he dado KILL a los procesos pero siguen apareciendo en la lista de process manager.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien los he eliminado desde la terminal pero siguen apareciendo.
Reinicie los servicios de Apache y Apache php-fpm pero no tengo resultados

¿Alguna recomendacion?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.